# How to control multiple form fields with similar js codes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wan to format user input to match money format with js; but I don't know how to apply js codes to more than one filed in a single form. Example of the code i want to extend is here
HTML

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="10,732.00">
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" value="1,202.00">
```

JS

```
/*!
 * accounting.js v0.4.2, copyright 2014 Open Exchange Rates, MIT license, https://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js
 */
(function(p,z){function q(a){return!!(""===a||a&&a.charCodeAt&&a.substr)}function m(a){return u?u(a):"[object Array]"===v.call(a)}function r(a){return"[object Object]"===v.call(a)}function s(a,b){var d,a=a||{},b=b||{};for(d in b)b.hasOwnProperty(d)&&null==a[d]&&(a[d]=b[d]);return a}function j(a,b,d){var c=[],e,h;if(!a)return c;if(w&&a.map===w)return a.map(b,d);for(e=0,h=a.length;e<h;e++)c[e]=b.call(d,a[e],e,a);return c}function n(a,b){a=Math.round(Math.abs(a));return isNaN(a)?b:a}function x(a){var b=c.settings.currency.format;"function"===typeof a&&(a=a());return q(a)&&a.match("%v")?{pos:a,neg:a.replace("-","").replace("%v","-%v"),zero:a}:!a||!a.pos||!a.pos.match("%v")?!q(b)?b:c.settings.currency.format={pos:b,neg:b.replace("%v","-%v"),zero:b}:a}var c={version:"0.4.1",settings:{currency:{symbol:"$",format:"%s%v",decimal:".",thousand:",",precision:2,grouping:3},number:{precision:0,grouping:3,thousand:",",decimal:"."}}},w=Array.prototype.map,u=Array.isArray,v=Object.prototype.toString,o=c.unformat=c.parse=function(a,b){if(m(a))return j(a,function(a){return o(a,b)});a=a||0;if("number"===typeof a)return a;var b=b||".",c=RegExp("[^0-9-"+b+"]",["g"]),c=parseFloat((""+a).replace(/\((.*)\)/,"-$1").replace(c,"").replace(b,"."));return!isNaN(c)?c:0},y=c.toFixed=function(a,b){var b=n(b,c.settings.number.precision),d=Math.pow(10,b);return(Math.round(c.unformat(a)*d)/d).toFixed(b)},t=c.formatNumber=c.format=function(a,b,d,i){if(m(a))return j(a,function(a){return t(a,b,d,i)});var a=o(a),e=s(r(b)?b:{precision:b,thousand:d,decimal:i},c.settings.number),h=n(e.precision),f=0>a?"-":"",g=parseInt(y(Math.abs(a||0),h),10)+"",l=3<g.length?g.length%3:0;return f+(l?g.substr(0,l)+e.thousand:"")+g.substr(l).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,"$1"+e.thousand)+(h?e.decimal+y(Math.abs(a),h).split(".")[1]:"")},A=c.formatMoney=function(a,b,d,i,e,h){if(m(a))return j(a,function(a){return A(a,b,d,i,e,h)});var a=o(a),f=s(r(b)?b:{symbol:b,precision:d,thousand:i,decimal:e,format:h},c.settings.currency),g=x(f.format);return(0<a?g.pos:0>a?g.neg:g.zero).replace("%s",f.symbol).replace("%v",t(Math.abs(a),n(f.precision),f.thousand,f.decimal))};c.formatColumn=function(a,b,d,i,e,h){if(!a)return[];var f=s(r(b)?b:{symbol:b,precision:d,thousand:i,decimal:e,format:h},c.settings.currency),g=x(f.format),l=g.pos.indexOf("%s")<g.pos.indexOf("%v")?!0:!1,k=0,a=j(a,function(a){if(m(a))return c.formatColumn(a,f);a=o(a);a=(0<a?g.pos:0>a?g.neg:g.zero).replace("%s",f.symbol).replace("%v",t(Math.abs(a),n(f.precision),f.thousand,f.decimal));if(a.length>k)k=a.length;return a});return j(a,function(a){return q(a)&&a.length<k?l?a.replace(f.symbol,f.symbol+Array(k-a.length+1).join(" ")):Array(k-a.length+1).join(" ")+a:a})};if("undefined"!==typeof exports){if("undefined"!==typeof module&&module.exports)exports=module.exports=c;exports.accounting=c}else"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define([],function(){return c}):(c.noConflict=function(a){return function(){p.accounting=a;c.noConflict=z;return c}}(p.accounting),p.accounting=c)})(this);

var input = document.getElementById('a');
input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    input.value = accounting.unformat(input.value);
    input.focus();
    input.select();
});
input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    input.value = accounting.formatMoney(input.value, '');
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    //input.value = accounting.unformat(input.value);
    //input.value = accounting.formatMoney(input.value, '');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Add a same class to all the inputs you want to have this behavior. I added `"test"`
- You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all the input element with `class="test"`
- Then use `forEach` to loop through them and add event listeners to them
- Use `this` to access the element inside the function.

Here is the code.

#### Javascript

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    this.value = accounting.unformat(this.value);
    this.focus();
    this.select();
  });

  input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.value = accounting.formatMoney(this.value, '');
  });

  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    this.value = accounting.unformat(this.value);
    this.value = accounting.formatMoney(this.value, '');
  });

})
```

#### Html

```
<input class="test" type="text" name="a" id="a" value="10,732.00">
<input class="test" type="text" name="b" id="b" value="1,202.00">
```